# How can I read the JSON data element value?

Tags: jquery

I guess this html is right

```
<span id="tag_8" data-translations="{&quot;en&quot;:&quot;cat&quot;}" class="myTag selected">chat</span>at

# generated with : 
#  %span.myTag{:id => "tag_" + tag_id.to_s, :'data-translations' => translations(tag_id).to_json}= tag
```

I am trying to read the translation from within a jquery script , but it's failing :

```
selectedTag = $('#tag-list li span.myTag.selected:first')
console.log 'translations: ' + selectedTag.data("translations", "en")
 =>   translations: [object Object]

#however
 console.log 'translations: ' + selectedTag.data("translations")
 =>  translations: {"en"=>"cat"}
```

Comment: Try `parseJSON()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: FYI: `selectedTag.data("translations", "en")` will set `data-translations`  to `en` instead of reading it. `[object Object]` is the string-representation of the jQuery object for the selectedTag element, since the setter-data-method will return the jQuery object, to support chaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to return cat you can do it like this

> $('#tag_8').data('translations').en

else if you want to return an object and save it to a variable you can do it like this `var obj = $('#tag_8').data('translations')` and use it like this `obj.en`

```
$('#tag_8').data('translations')

returns

Object {en: "cat"}

/////////////////

$('#tag_8').data('translations').en

returns "cat"
```

Comment: Thanks, effectively no need for parseJSON :
      console.log 'translations: ' + selectedTag.data("translations")
      console.log selectedTag.data('translations').en

Comment: However if  'en' is a variable , how can I display it ?
$('#tag_8').data('translations')[variable]  ??

Comment: Got it !  :   console.log selectedTag.data('translations')['en']
console.log selectedTag.data('translations')[var_lang]